# Problem in computing the gradient of a function

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I want to differentiate a vector with respect to another using TensorFlow. I am unable to write and visualize the output (just started my journey on TensorFlow)

I am attaching the code snippet I have tried.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 120) 
y = np.sinh(x) 

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axhline(color="gray", zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(color="gray", zorder=-1)
plt.show()

X = tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.constant(y, dtype=tf.float32)
gradient = tf.gradients(Y, X)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
```

I am unable to output the gradient. I also tried a placeholder for the gradients but cannot figure out how to go about.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Y` doesn't depend on `X`. The way you have defined them they are just two independent tensors. This is probably what you want:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 120) 
y_data = np.sinh(x_data) 

plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.axhline(color="gray", zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(color="gray", zorder=-1)
plt.show() # <-- shows image

x = tf.constant(x_data, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.math.sinh(x) # <-- `y` is a function of `x`
grads = tf.gradients(y, x)

# init = tf.global_variables_initializer() # <-- No need, you don't have variables here
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(grads)) # <-- prints long array
```

Comment: Thanks this works, I still have a question. Why should the explicit dependence of y on x be given? we just give two sets of data and ask to differentiate one data with respect to the other. This is true of auto-diff tools like Tapenade. If I just specify y=tf.constant(y_data, dtype=tf.float32), I am getting a typeError which I am unable to understand why!

Comment: To differentiate TF needs to know what function to use. When you provide two tensors there's no way to know what function to use. When you use `y = tf.math.sinh(x)` TF knows what function is the derivative of `tf.math.sinh()` and it returns you the values of that function. Automatic differentiation using Gradient Tape is used with eager execution but it does more or less the same thing. Regarding error that your receive, the problem is probably in `y_data`. I can't say without seeing the full traceback.